# merging multiple suppliers formats into 1 data format

Tags: php, xml, csv, e-commerce

I have been doing a research about how to import multiple products from x suppliers into one standard format and inserting that in the database, and eventually showing those products on an e-commerce website. My possible results so far have been:

- data  distribution where they have 1 big data pool of suppliers,
  returning their  products through an API.
- sending a standard format to the suppliers (CSV, XML) for them to fill in and send it back.

For the 2nd one I've been researching to do it the following way: Supplier upload their file (CSV, XML) to the FTP, with a script pulling those files from the FTP and converting that with PHP and inserting it into the database. Now with this, the supplier has to upload a new file whenever they update their products, updating the database.

The problem with the 1st one is that not every possible supplier is available in there, and dont wanna pay for that service. The problem with the 2nd one is that not every supplier wanna fill in a (new) standard data format for their products.

Are there any other possible solution to achieve this, or any tips I could get regarding this question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than demand that suppliers use your format, why don't you write functions to normalize the data provided by each supplier that it works with your database? Seems like it's your responsibility to figure out how to deal with their data, not theirs to provide data in ever conceivable format.